# Ui router not working?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

My simple router doesnt seem to work, here is my app.js

```
var module = angular.module('ngFirstApp',['ui.router']);

module.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider.state("home",{
            url: "/home",
            template: "This is home"
        });
});

module.controller('ngController',function($scope){
        $scope.greeting = 'hello world';
});
```

and my html is this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="ngFirstApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My first app in Angular js</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/libs/bootstrap-css-only/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/libs/bootstrap-css-only/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
</head>
<body ng-controller="ngController">
    <div>
        <h1>{{ greeting }}</h1>
        What the heck is goin on here!!
        <div ui-view></div>
    </div>
    <!-- This is angularjs itself -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/angular/angular.js"></script>

    <!-- These came from cdnjs angular-ui-bootstrap -->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/libs/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Ui router -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.4.0/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <!-- These are custom files -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

when I go to localhost:3000/home, it saying cannot get home? whats wrong with my code.. please noob angularjs

Comment: try this localhost:3000/#/home

Comment: Thanks I actually tried putting `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');` now it seems to be adding `#!/home` and seems to be doing okay but i know about html5mode(true) will this fix this..? thanks for ur help again

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution as we are learning angularjs.

When you are using a route and you typed in the URL that you havent set up for like the state

`localhost:2311/words-not-set-in-your-state-declaration`

you need to put `urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/your-default-state');`

and so you dont get a `#!/state-here`, you got to turn the html5mode on exactly as this:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({enabled:true,requireBase: false});
```

**NOT** `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` otherwise your browser console will complain :)